# Несколько циклов соединить в один

Tags: python

У меня задание создать "генератор паролей" и на вход подаётся 6 вопросов что-то вроде "укажите количество паролей для генерации" или "включать ли строчные буквы". В связи с этим возник вопрос. А что если пользователь на вопрос "включать ли строчные буквы" ответит цифрой или пробелом (случайно или намеренно неважно) и как мне его попросить именно на этом вопросе попросить ввести данные корректно. Как с помощью while зациклить одно условие, пока не будет True or False я знаю. Но не хочется для 6 вопросов делать 6 циклов while. Есть же способ производительнее и быстрее, чем 6 циклов подряд. Также не хочется заставлять пользователя, если он допустил ошибку где-то в середине, вводить ответы на вопросы с самого начале. Подскажите пожалуйста новичку!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `while` можно использовать сколько угодно условий. Например:

```
while x != 0 or y > 2 or z == "ok":
```

Comment: Это не решает проблемы. Если пользователю задали 3 вопроса, на которые он корректно дал ответ (в зависимости от вопросов) и на 4-ый вопрос дал неккоректный ответ, а впереди ещё несколько вопросов, то при использовании цикла while он будет отвечать на все вопросы заново. А хочется, чтобы он ответил вопрос, на который дал неккоректный ответ

Comment: Верно. Поэтому от нескольких циклов подряд никуда не деться ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ну а если будет допустим 100 вопросов. Что же, придётся 100 циклов запихивать? Комп не выдержит наверное)
Я не знаю нагруженность одного цикла с условием, но если таких будет n-ое кол-во, то это никому хорошо не будет)

Comment: почему он не выдержит-то?

Comment: Вообше-то это всё одно условие...

Comment: Я предполагаю, не знаю наверняка. Если комп сможет выдержать и код будет стабильно работать, то тогда проблем нет. Но даже если всё будет ок с производительностью, но как же тогда громоздкость. Через генератор списков и т.п. точно не получится, тогда из-за такого большого кол-ва циклов код будет, чисто визуально, нагружен ИМХО

Comment: что выдержать-то? Во-первых, эти 6-10-100 циклов не будет работать одновременно. Во-вторых, прямо сейчас ваш компьютер крутит намного больше циклов, чем вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @чистов_n ну так и 6 условий для генерации пароля тоже "одно условие"...

Comment: @Эникейщик аа, тогда да, согласен. Просто стремлюсь к красивому коду, но если никак не получится, то пускай хоть так)
А через рекурсию тут никак не получится?